# Colormake for silent mode

Tags: ubuntu, makefile

So, I've installed *colormake* in **Xubuntu 18.04**, setted `alias make='colormake'` and it works perfectly when I just type `make`:

[image: terminal with color fonts]

The problem is, if I try to use make in silent/quiet mode, aka `make -s`, the output is only gray:

[image: terminal with only gray font]

I think I'm missing something about how either *make* or *colormake* works. Anyone knows how to make it work properly? Unfortunately, I've seen that *colormake* is not mantained anymore, so I guess there's not really something official to look for...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found time to look into it myself, after some days.

It seems like it had nothing to do with the silent mode: it was simply to change some things around in the **Perl** script `/usr/share/colormake/colormake.pl`. I do not know Perl, but since the script is easy enough (*and somewhat bash-like*) I was able to spent some time to edit it how I wanted.

If it helps anyone, here's what I did:

```perl
# Some useful color codes, see end of file for more.
# tput used to automatically detect best combination for current shell
$bold=`tput bold`;
$normal=`tput sgr0`;

$col_black  =   "\033[30m";
$col_red    =   "\033[31m";
$col_green  =   "\033[32m";
$col_yellow     =   "\033[33m";
$col_blue   =   "\033[34m";
$col_magenta    =   "\033[35m";
$col_cyan   =   "\033[36m";
$col_ltgray     =   "\033[37m";
$col_drkgray    =   "\033[1;30m";
$col_purple     =   "\033[35m",
$col_white  =   "\033[37m",

$col_norm   =       "\033[00m";
$col_background =       "\033[07m";
$col_brighten   =       "\033[01m";
$col_underline  =       "\033[04m";
$col_blink  =       "\033[05m";

# Customize colors here...
$col_default    =       $col_ltgray;
$col_gcc    =       $col_magenta . $col_brighten;
$col_make   =       $col_cyan;
$col_filename   =       $col_drkgray;
$col_linenum    =       $col_blue . $col_brighten;
$col_trace  =       $col_green;
$col_warningtag =   $col_yellow . $bold;
$col_warning    =       $col_yellow;
$col_comment    =       $col_drkgray;
$col_errortag   =       $col_red . $bold;
$col_error  =   $col_red;
$error_highlight =      $col_brighten;

# Read in config files: system first, then user
for $file ("/usr/share/colormake/colormake.rc", "$ENV{HOME}/.colormakerc")
{
    unless (!-f $file or do $file)
    {
        warn "couldn't parse $file: $@" if $@;
    }
}

# Get size of terminal
$lines = shift @ARGV || 0;
$cols  = shift @ARGV || 0;
$cols -= 19;

$in = 'unknown';
$| = 1;
$skip = 0;

# Treat cases
while (<>)
{
    $orgline = $thisline = $_;

    # Remove multiple spaces
    $thisline =~ s/  \+/ /g;

    # Skip lines
    $skip--;
    if ($skip < 0)
    {
        $skip = 0;
    }

    # make[1]: Entering directory `/blah/blah/blah'
    if ($thisline =~ s/^((p|g)?make\[)/$col_make$1/x)
    {
        $in = 'make';
    } # Some compiler tools
    elsif ($thisline =~ s/^(\s*(libtool:\s*)?((compile|link):\s*)?(([[:ascii:]]+-)?g?(cc|\+\+)|(g|c)\+\+|clang|CC|CXX).*)$/$col_gcc$1$col_norm/)
    {
        $in = 'gcc';

        if ($thisline =~ /\W-MF\W/)
        {
            $skip = 2;
        }
    } # Comments
    elsif ($thisline =~ s/^\#/$col_comment#$1/x)
    {
        $in = 'comment';
    }
    elsif (!$skip && $thisline =~ /^(\s*\(|\[|a(r|wk)|c(p|d|h(mod|own))|do(ne)?|e(cho|lse)|f(ind|or)|i(f|nstall)|mv|perl|r(anlib|m(dir)?)|s(e(d|t)|trip)|tar)\s+/)
    {
        $in = $1;
    }
    elsif ($thisline !~ /^mv\W/)
    {
        # Do interesting things if make is compiling something.
        if (($thisline !~ /[,:]$/) && ($thisline !~ /warning/))
        {
            if ($thisline =~ /[,:]$/) {
                print "\t\t\t\t[,:]\$ matched --> '$thisline\n'";
            }
            $thisline =~ s|(error:\s+)(.*)$|$col_errortag ERROR: $normal$col_error$2$normal|;
            $thisline =~ s/(\d+:\s+)/$1$col_default$col_error/;
            $thisline = $thisline . $col_norm;
        }
        else
        {
            # Warning
            if ($thisline =~ /(warning:\s+)(.*)$|/) {
                $thisline =~ s|(warning:\s+)(.*)$|$col_warning WARNING: $normal$col_warning$2$normal|;
            }
        }
            # In file included from main.cpp:38:
            # main.cpp: In function int main(...)':
            $thisline =~ s/(In\sf(unction|ile))/$col_trace$1/x;

            # /blah/blah/blah.cpp:123:
            $thisline =~ s|^([\.\/:]*)([[:graph:]]+)(\.[a-z])|$col_filename$1$2$3$col_default|;

            # Line number
            $thisline =~ s|:(\d+)([:,])|:$col_linenum$1$col_default$2|;
        #}
    }

    if ($thisline !~ /^\s+/)
    {
        print $col_norm, $col_default;
    }
    print $thisline;
}

print $col_norm;
```

and here's the result
[image: final output]